# ssh keychain for git pull cron

Tags: ssh, git, keychain

I am a bit of a newbie with linux, so must apologize straight away if this is something obvious and/or silly.

I am trying to create a git pull cronjob that gets update from GitHub repo every few minutes.

Now the problem is that I can not get it working without entering pass-phrase every time cron runs.

ssh-agent and ssh-add does not do the trick as they loose the passwords every time user logs out. So I got the guide `http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-passwordless-login-with-keychain-for-scripts/` and followed it, but still no results.

I can not seem to get the keychain working properly. I think.

The steps I have done:

- Installed the keychain from RPMforge.
- Edited the `vi $HOME/.bash_profile` to include:

  /usr/bin/keychain $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa

  source $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
- And according to the guide, after I re-log, keychain should be working and I should not need to enter the pass-phrase every time I `ssh -T git@github.com`

I am probably missing something, but can not seem to figure out what. Maybe someone has some suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this link to solved  same problem  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994663/git-push-via-cron)

its help full  to you..

Comment: Cheers, I am looking into it.

Comment: ok..if you solved your probs .let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I went through all of it and found a flaws. Cheers for the source !